# Unexpected file found in package directory: /Users/Chintan/force-app/main/default/messageChannels/messageDemo.messageChannels-meta.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to create a message channel via VS Code in my salesforceDX project. I have followed the document provided by the salesforce.

When I am trying to deploy that message channel file I am getting the below error.

> ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Unexpected file found in package directory: /Users/Chintan/force-app/main/default/messageChannels/messageDemo.messageChannels-meta.xml

Can anyone please suggest to me how I can solve this issue?

Here is my project

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filename is incorrect. Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_intro),

> The LightningMessageChannel file name follows the format messageChannelName.messageChannel-meta.xml.

rather than `.messageChannels-meta.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, @David.